# Compile Groovy project with -indy

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

where in intellij can I set the compile flag `-indy` to support `InvokeDynamic`? I have already swapped all libraries in the `$GROOVY_HOME$/lib` folder with ones in `$GROOVY_HOME$/indy` is this sufficient or i still need to add that flag somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is under File >> Settings, then Compiler > Groovy Compiler.

[image: Invoke Dynamic support option]